Poner un progress bar en segundo plano c sharp
Tengo un programa que funciona en red y cuando cargo la base de datos tarda algo de tiempo y se me congela la pantalla. Me gustaria poner un imagen gif o un progress bar que me muestre que la base de datos esta cargandose y sobre todo que no se congele mi formulario. Eh escuchado de metodos asincronos pero no se como hacerle, debido a que no tengo experiencia en la programacion de C Sharp. A continuacion pongo el codigo de lo que estoy haciedo (todo esto lo hago dentro del evento load del formulario):
        List<string> lstSQL = GenerarSenteciasSQL();
        List<string> lstTablas = new List<string>();
        DataSet dsTables = new DataSet();
        lstTablas.AddRange(lTablas);
        try
        {
            dsTables = CNSentenciasSQL.dsTablas(lstSQL, lstTablas);
            dtParametrosSYS = dsTables.Tables["tblParametros"];
            dtParametrosSYS.TableName = "dtParametrosSYS";
            dtEmpresas = dsTables.Tables["tblEmpresas"];
            dtEmpresas.TableName = "dtEmpresas";
            //
            CargarCultivos(dsTables.Tables["tblCultivos"].Copy());
            ListarCultivos(cbxCultivo, dsTables);
            ListarVariedades(cbxVariedad, 0, dsTables);
            ListarBodegas(cbxBodega, dsTables);
            ListarEjidos(cbxEjido, dsTables);
            ListarMunicipios(cbxMunicipio, dsTables);
            ListarEstados(cbxEstado, dsTables);
            ListarBoletas(dsTables);
        }
        finally
        {
            dsTables.Dispose();
            dsTables = null;
        }

Espero me haya explicado.

Justamente el programa deja de responder porque estás ejecutando código que toma mucho tiempo en completarse en el hilo principal. La solución es bastante simple: mover el trabajo a otro hilo. El cómo puede variar. Desde usar Task.Run() a crear el hilo manualmente. https://stackify.com/c-threading-and-multithreading-a-guide-with-examples/

Evita operaciones en el hilo principal, te sugiero usar Task (Programación asincrónica).
Puedes crear un método Asíncrono para realizar el procesamiento.
private async Task CargaBasedeDatosAsync()
{
  //* Aquì realiza tu proceso de carga de datos
}


Complementando la respuesta de Jorgesys, lo ideal es manejarlo con hilos.
En Windwos Form y WPF existen los Background Workers, que sirven para mandar tareas a otro hilo y tiene una función especial para gestionar progress bar, aquí hay un ejemplo de como implementarlo aquí
